# contentEditable text is reversed

Tags: javascript, logic, contenteditable

Following this simple logic, here is a very simple regex-based parser.

```
// Input: The **quick** brown fox **jumps** over the lazy dog
let phrase = "The **quick** brown fox **jumps** over the lazy dog"

// Operation
phrase = phrase.replace(/(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/g, "<strong>$2</strong>")

// Output:  The <strong>quick</strong> brown fox <strong>jumps</strong> over the lazy dog
console.log(phrase)
```

However, I'd like my result to be shown dynamically in a `contentEditable` `div`

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const editor = document.createElement('div')

editor.contentEditable = 'true'
editor.style.cssText = 'background: lightblue; height: 50vh; width: 50vw;'

editor.addEventListener('input', () => {
        editor.innerText = editor.innerText.replace(/(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/g, "<strong>$2</strong>")
})

body.appendChild(editor)
```

Issue: **Hello World** returns **dlroW olleH**, my results are reversed. How is this fixable?

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const editor = document.createElement('div')

editor.contentEditable = 'true'
editor.style.cssText = 'background: lightblue; height: 50vh; width: 50vw;'

editor.addEventListener('input', () => {
        editor.innerText = editor.innerText.replace(/(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/g, "<strong>$2</strong>")
})

body.appendChild(editor)
```

Note: I do not wish to use an external library or other dependencies, I'd like to learn and understand the issue.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to understand. each time you replace the innertext of contenteditable the cursor resets it's position so what u want to do is to set the cursor each time you change the innertext which can be achieved using range interface.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const editor = document.createElement('div')

editor.contentEditable = 'true'
editor.style.cssText = 'background: lightblue; height: 50vh; width: 50vw;'

editor.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let v = editor.innerText.replace(/(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/g, "<strong>$2</strong>");
        editor.innerText = v;
    var range = document.createRange(),
    sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(editor.childNodes[0],v.length);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
})

body.appendChild(editor)
```

**this is not the perfect handling but this is what u asked for.**

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't work with line break...

Comment: @BenoîtLahoz What do you mean by it doesn't work with line break?

Comment: When adding a line break (user input), the selection (and its caret representation) stays at the previous line.